# error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, int, varchar

I'm getting following error for my code:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '(CASE WHEN
>   ROW_NUM = ' to data type int.

What am I doing wrong?

```
DECLARE @N          INT = 6, 
        @I          INT = 0, 
        @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX) 


BEGIN
 SET @SQL = '(CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = '+@I+'THEN problem ELSE NULL END) ';
 SET @I = @I+1;
END

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
  @SQL
```

Comment: Surely missing a space before THEN.

Comment: You need to do `CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(12))` in your string concatenation.

Comment: i changed the code to the following   DECLARE @N          INT = 6, 
        I          INT = 0, 
        SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX) 
      

BEGIN
 SET SQL = '(CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = '+CAST(@I AS VARCHAR(12))+' THEN DX_NAME ELSE NULL END) ';
 SET I = @I+1;
END

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL 
  SQL    and getting following error   "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'."

Comment: @vdohnal i added space before THEN but same error......

Comment: @Var edit the question with the new code please.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a portion of a loop. Why are you using a loop here? If you are not using a loop why do you need to use dynamic sql? More than likely the best answer in reworking your code instead of making the current direction functional.

Answer (score 1):

Based on just the code you posted, you're missing your SELECT statement and a FROM clause.  You're also assuming that you have a column named `ROW_NUM` and a column named `problem`:

```
DECLARE @N          INT = 6, 
        @I          INT = 0, 
        @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX) 


BEGIN

  SET @SQL = 'SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = '+CAST(@I as VARCHAR(10))+' 
  THEN problem ELSE NULL END FROM MyTable';
 SET @I = @I+1;

END
print @SQL
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

However, it also looks like you're trying to execute a `WHILE` loop without actually defining the `WHILE`, which you would do like this:

```
DECLARE @N          INT = 6, 
        @I          INT = 0, 
        @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX) 

WHILE @I <= @N   -- new code

 BEGIN
  SET @SQL = 'SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = '+CAST(@I as VARCHAR(10))+' THEN problem ELSE NULL END FROM MyTable';
  SET @I = @I+1;
  PRINT @SQL
  EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL 
 END
```

I think you are actually looking for something like this:

```
SELECT 'Problem', *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW_NUM) rn FROM MyTable) s
WHERE rn <> ROW_NUM
```

Sample with dummy data:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ROW_NUM INT, SomeData VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (1, 'foo')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (2, 'zip')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (3, 'yak')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (5, 'lop')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (6, 'cow')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (ROW_NUM, SomeData) VALUES (7, 'moo')


SELECT 'Problem', *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ROW_NUM) rn FROM @MyTable) s
WHERE rn <> ROW_NUM
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: You need to `Cast int to varchar` and Try to Execute Printed SQL for error Probe

```
DECLARE @N          INT = 6, 
        @I          INT = 0, 
        @SQL        NVARCHAR(MAX) 


BEGIN

  SET @SQL = '(CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = '+CAST(@I as VARCHAR(10))+' 
  THEN problem ELSE NULL END) ';
 SET @I = @I+1;
END
print @SQL
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: @ganesh_develkar I tried running your code and i'm getting the following error. "(CASE WHEN ROW_NUM = 0 
  THEN problem ELSE NULL END) 
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
"